# failed to install vim on my ubuntu

Tags: software-installation, updates, vim

I've having problem installing vim on my Ubuntu. After running `sudo apt-get install vim`, I get the following error message:

```
Ign:1 http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 vim-runtime all 2:8.1.2269-1ubuntu5.7
Ign:2 http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 vim amd64 2:8.1.2269-1ubuntu5.7
Ign:1 http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 vim-runtime all 2:8.1.2269-1ubuntu5.7
Err:2 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 vim amd64 2:8.1.2269-1ubuntu5.7
  Temporary failure resolving 'ca.archive.ubuntu.com'
Ign:1 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 vim-runtime all 2:8.1.2269-1ubuntu5.7
Err:1 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 vim-runtime all 2:8.1.2269-1ubuntu5.7
  Temporary failure resolving 'ca.archive.ubuntu.com'
E: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/v/vim/vim-runtime_8.1.2269-1ubuntu5.7_all.deb  Temporary failure resolving 'ca.archive.ubuntu.com'
E: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/v/vim/vim_8.1.2269-1ubuntu5.7_amd64.deb  Temporary failure resolving 'ca.archive.ubuntu.com'
E: Unable to fetch some archives, try running apt-get update or apt-get --fix-missing.
```

While I tried running `apt-get update`, it gives me this error message:

```
E: Could not open lock file /var/lib/apt/lists/lock - open (13: Permission denied)
E: Unable to lock directory /var/lib/apt/lists/
W: Problem unlinking the file /var/cache/apt/pkgcache.bin - RemoveCaches (13: Permission denied)
W: Problem unlinking the file /var/cache/apt/srcpkgcache.bin - RemoveCaches (13: Permission denied)
```

Can anyone help me to look at what is the problem? I would assume it is a permission issue but not sure how to fix it. Thanks.

Comment: The first issue is a name resolution problem, possibly with the Canadian mirrors being unavailable. The second issue looks like an `apt` run without `sudo`. For the first item, you may be able to resolve this by changing which servers your system connects to when updating. I generally use the `gb.archive.ubuntu.com` servers as they're consistently fast and available ... despite being on the other side of the planet for me 

Comment: Thank you very much matigo, can you please kindly indicate how to change the server of the system connects to when updating?